# TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Tags: python, list, range

```py
import os
import sys

listed = []

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('/'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.png'):
            listed.append(filename)
            for name in range(len(list(0, 10))):    
                print(name)
```

I want this script to look for all the .png files but only print only up till ten but when run the script  it gives me an error:

> TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by `list(0,10)`? This is causing the error

Comment: The error message is exact. `list` expected 0 or 1 arguments as iterable. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.

Comment: I think they meant `for name in range(len(list[0]), 10):`

Comment: @alec `list[0]` can cause error, too. If you don't override `list` name.

Comment: Can you explain purpose of most inner `for`-loop(or range that you want)? Then I can tell how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` you got is because of:
`for name in range(len(list(0, 10))):`

You passed the `range` function the `end` parameter to iterate from `0` to `end - 1`. That's OK. But the problem is where you want to create list and length of it. The `list` function accepts an iterator like `tuple`.

So you can do it by:

```py
list((0, 10))
```

But if you want to print up to ten filenames, use simply:

```py
listed = []
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('/'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.png'):
            listed.append(filename)

    for index in range(10): 
        print(listed[index])
```